Azure AD B2C ACS URL returns error "AADB2C90046"
Users are encountering an error after successful authentication through SiteMinder (external IdP). Following authentication, SiteMinder sends a SAML Response to Azure AD B2C's ACS endpoint, but B2C returns the below error:
{"status":"400","errorCode":"AADB2C90046","message":"We are having trouble signing you in. You might want to try starting your session over from the beginning."}

Application Insights didn't reveal the specific reason for the "AADB2C90046" error.

Did you do a SAML trace? The error is often inside the SAML packet.

Yes, we did capture the network traffic to get the SAML Response. From the Application Insights, it seems that "ClaimsExchangeMessageValidationHandler" throws this error message, though it does not report specifics of  message validation failure. What I should be looking for inside the SAML Packet to troubleshoot this issue?
